# ubuntu 12.04 can not transfer parameter using php 's shell_exec function

Tags: php, parameters, ubuntu-12.04, shell-exec

on ubuntu 10.4 server.
`test.php`

```
$id="0.1";
$cmd=". ~/test.sh ".$id; 
shell_exec($cmd);
```

test.sh

```
echo "$1" >> a.txt
echo "count:$#" >> a.txt
```

after run `php test.php,a.txt` shows:

```
0.1
count:1
```

while on ubuntu 12.04 server `a.txt` shows:

```
(nothing display)
count:0
```

so any one know the difference between ubuntu 12.04 and ubuntu 10.4 when transfer parameters using php's `shell_exec function`

Comment: What if you do 2>&1 at the end ?

Comment: @nixgadgets,you mean add '2>&1' to the end of (echo "$1" >> a.txt) ?,i tried,but still failed.

Comment: what i want is to transfer the parameter "0.1" to test.sh.so that in test.sh ,the variable $1 's value is "0.1"

Comment: on ubuntu 10.4,php version is 5.3.2.on ubuntu 12.04,php version is 5.3.10. is it because the different version of php cause this issue?

Comment: sorry i couldnt reply any earlier mate. not have either of these two on my current system its hard to tell whats going. but you might want to try adding "echo $SHELL" to the script you are running to make sure the same shell is executed. if you dont specify a directive in the script i think it uses dash by default. Let me know.

Comment: @nixgadgets i add #!/bin/bash to test.sh,but it still not working.